# Как выбрать из div ссылки у которых есть тег strong?

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Например

```html
<a href="https://">Какая то ссылка <strong>(0)</strong></a>
```

ссылки которые не имеют в себе `strong` не нужны.

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin перевели)

Comment: Урок для новичков как сделать парсер https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpJ3Cu8WBC8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Варианты:

1. Можно через css-селектор [задать условие](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational), чтобы выборка была для тех `<a>`, у которых есть вложенный `<strong>`: `a:has(strong)`
2. Или запросить все `<a>`, а у них проверить наличие вложенного `<strong>`

Пример:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div>
    <a href="https://">Какая то ссылка <strong>(0)</strong></a>
    <a href="https://">Какая то ссылка (1)</a>
    <div>
        <a href="https://">Какая то ссылка <strong>(2)</strong></a>
    </div>
</div>
"""
root = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for a in root.select('a:has(strong)'):
    print(a)
# <a href="https://">Какая то ссылка <strong>(0)</strong></a>
# <a href="https://">Какая то ссылка <strong>(2)</strong></a>

print()

for a in root.select('a'):
    if a.strong is None:
        continue
    print(a)
# <a href="https://">Какая то ссылка <strong>(0)</strong></a>
# <a href="https://">Какая то ссылка <strong>(2)</strong></a>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я Вам очень благодарен.

Comment: @ДенисКононенко, пожалуйста :)